# How can I get a list of youtube videos that have more than an X amount of likes from a specific category

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I've searched everywhere, **Google**, **Forums**, **STACK**, **Youtube documentation** and I have not found a way to `GET` videos that are form a specific category and have a decent amount of likes! E.g `select * videos from api where likes > 1000 and category like %surfing%,%skiing%`

Personally I think the youtube API documentation sucks. It doesn't explain things vary clearly and there are limited examples.

Example if I was querying the youtube database (pseudo code):

```
select * from videos where categories LIKE '%SURFING%' and numLikes > 30000
```

In theory it should be as simple as the code snippet below, but it's not. (pseudo code)

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet,likes>=200, categories=Surfing, cars, documentaries', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    ));

foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      echo $searchResult['categoryNAME'] . "  " . $searchResult['videoID'];
```

Has anyone got any knowledge to how I can achieve this? Another pseudo code documentation to help you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

> Select * videos from the youtube api where the videos category can be
>   SURFING, SNOWBOARDING and the likes on each video have to be > 10000

Comment: What api do you use for this ? v3 ?

Comment: Yes, v3. v2 is depreciated isn't it or at least is being depreciated? @wilson

Comment: v2 is deprecated, you are correct. However, I don't believe there is a way to filter the results by like count and a specified category in v3. You'd have to search by the keyword, get the list of relevant video IDs, then use videos.list on each video to check the `likeCount`, which is available under statistics (a part that search doesn't have).

Comment: wow! The youtube api is lacking a lot of functionality. You'd think that adding that type of functionality would be easy...

So your saying I might have to search by `keyword (title)`. Interesting, I'll probably do that then. I'm just wondering is there anyway of getting more than 50 results?? Because I'd like to sort of get a database table going of these videos. @not_a_bot

Comment: Sorry, the max is 50 and you need to use paging to get the rest of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this as the YouTube v3 API does not allow you to query or order by likes.

You could try searching the category and ordering results by views or rating, then loop through the data returned and drop videos with likes less than X. It's not as good but it's something.

Comment: Good idea. Might have to do that! The amount of results will still be limited to 50  though right?

Comment: They come in sets of 50. Then you can use next page token to get the next 50 results, and so on, up to 500.